# Why is apache ignoring my virtual host instructions

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd

## Background

Admittedly, this is a nube question. What I want to do is to simply install the [beanstalk console](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) and make it run from say, app.beanstalk.com on my local machine

## What I have tried

so I copied the files into my OSX webroot (`/Library/WebServer/Documents`)and it works fine, If I go to

```
http://localhost/beanstalk_console/public/
```

it loads as expected.

So now I did this to make it load from app.beanstalk.com:

**/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/beanstalk_console/public"
    ServerName app.beanstalk.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**private/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       app.beanstalk.com
```

keep in mind this is what I have in **httpdconf**

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any   
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## Problem

when I go to http://app.beanstalk.com on my localhost, it simply goes to the webroot (ie `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and shows me the "it works" page). What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that file `private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.com` (weird extension for apache config file btw) is included in main config?

Comment: Can you post the full `httpdconf`? I think you are missing the include for your `httpd-vhosts.com`. Usually it looks in a certain folder, looking for files ending in `.conf`.

Comment: that's it! it worked! didin't include that line